# Passing a const lvalue reference as rvalue reference

Tags: c++, templates, constants, perfect-forwarding, const-cast

I have a function that accepts an rvalue reference:

```
template<typename... Ts>
void foo(std::tuple<Ts...>&& t)
{
    processFoo(std::forward<std::tuple<Ts...>>(t));
}
```

and another function that accepts an lvalue reference:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(const T& t);
```

I want `bar` to be able to bind with both lvalues and rvalues, so it's signature is OK. Then, I want to call `foo` with `t` from bar. For this code:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(const T& t);
{
    foo(t);
}
```

my compiler rightfully complains that there is no matching function for call to `foo(...)`, as `std::tuple<_blahblahblah>` and `const std::tuple<_blah>` have incompatible cv-qualifiers. So I do the following:

```
template<typename T>
void bar(const T& t);
{
    foo(std::forward<T>(const_cast<T&>(t)));
}
```

but the `const_cast` looks like a workaround!

Does the above forwarding code look OK and idiomatic? Maybe it would be better to overload `foo` for other reference types and cv-qualifiers? Or is there any "even more universal" reference, which would help to get rid of `const_cast`?

Comment: `foo` doesn't modify its parameter or take ownership of it. Declare it as accepting a `const` reference as well. I see no reason to accept a forwarding reference here.

Comment: `std::tuple<Ts...>&& t` is not a forwarding reference.

Comment: @StoryTeller in real code it performs forwarding, so I need rvalue reference. I modified the code example.

Comment: Well, as Hold pointed out and I missed, this isn't a forwarding reference at all. Just a regular rvalue reference to a `std::tuple`. So again, just go with `const`, or drop it entirely. You aren't actually doing any forwarding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This cannot work before `std::tuple<Ts...> &&` is **not** a forwarding reference, it is a simple rvalue-reference, and you cannot bind a const lvalue-ref to a rvalue-ref - Change your code to:

```
template<typename Tuple>
void foo(Tuple&& t) {
    processFoo(std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}
```

And you will have a real forwarding reference, and your code will work.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Thanks!